# Integer in an interval with maximized number of trailing zero bits

Tags: algorithm, scala, bit-manipulation

Sought is an efficient algorithm that finds the unique integer in an interval `[a, b]` which has the maximum number of trailing zeros in its binary representation (`a` and `b` are integers > 0):

```
def bruteForce(a: Int, b: Int): Int =
  (a to b).maxBy(Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(_))

def binSplit(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
  require(a > 0 && a <= b)
  val res = ???
  assert(res == bruteForce(a, b))
  res
}
```

here are some examples

```
bruteForce(  5,   7) ==   6 // binary 110 (1 trailing zero)
bruteForce(  1, 255) == 128 // binary 10000000
bruteForce(129, 255) == 192 // binary 11000000
```

etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one finds the number of zeros:

```
// Requires a>0
def mtz(a: Int, b: Int, mask: Int = 0xFFFFFFFE, n: Int = 0): Int = {
  if (a > (b & mask)) n
  else mtz(a, b, mask<<1, n+1)
}
```

This one returns the number with those zeros:

```
// Requires a > 0
def nmtz(a: Int, b: Int, mask: Int = 0xFFFFFFFE): Int = {
  if (a > (b & mask)) b & (mask>>1)
  else nmtz(a, b, mask<<1)
}
```

I doubt the log(log(n)) solution has a small enough constant term to beat this.  (But you could do binary search on the number of zeros to get log(log(n)).)

Comment: wow, great! did you just come up with this or did you have that lying around? is this some kind of standard algorithm that goes by a name?

Comment: @Rex: This looks close to my narrative version.  If it's the same then after each step you're decreasing the number of trailing zeroes.  So there's no need to search at all?

Comment: @Sciss - I just came up with this.  It probably is named after the first person who just came up with it and named it.  @John - There's no need to do the "if less, if more" thing because masking always reduces b.

Comment: @Rex I'm not a Scala programmer so I'll need to study your code. :) But I just didn't understand your comment about "you could do a binary search".

Comment: @John - I started with `0xFFFFFFFF - ((1<<1) - 1)`, i.e. one zero, and kept increasing the number of zeros until something happened.  But I could also have started with 16 zeros (`(1<<16)-1`) and if the criterion failed jumped to 8, or if it succeeded jumped to 24, and in that way done a binary search on the number of zeros (stopping when I had a pair where `n` worked and `n+1` failed).  This would give `O(log(32))` steps, but much more constant work.  It might be a win for 64 bit integers.

Comment: @Rex I decided to [take a shot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156502/integer-in-an-interval-with-maximized-number-of-trailing-zero-bits/6158225#6158225) at beating your algorithm with binary search. :-) It's faster for positive random number, and very close for small numbers. I thought you might enjoy my approach.

Answer (score 4):

I decided to take Rex's challenge and produce something faster. :-)

```
// requires a > 0
def mtz2(a: Int, b: Int, mask: Int = 0xffff0000, shift: Int = 8, n: Int = 16): Int = {
  if (shift == 0) if (a > (b & mask)) n - 1 else n
  else if (a > (b & mask)) mtz2(a, b, mask >> shift, shift / 2, n - shift)
  else mtz2(a, b, mask << shift, shift / 2, n + shift)
}
```

Benchmarked with

```
import System.{currentTimeMillis => now}
def time[T](f: => T): T = {
  val start = now
  try { f } finally { println("Elapsed: " + (now - start)/1000.0 + " s") }
}

val range = 1 to 200
time(f((a, b) => mtz(a, b)))
time(f((a, b) => mtz2(a, b)))
```

Comment: nice! with a loop of 10000000 and pre-calculated random intervals, mtz runs after warm up for around 0.74 seconds and mtz2 for around 0.52 seconds in the REPL, which is a speedup of roughly 30%.

Comment: Nice one :)  (P.S. This question is the first time I've ever done bit twiddling where I've appreciated the signed-shift operator....)

Comment: @Rex Actually, me too. :-) I see I missed the `f` definition in the code above. I'll see if I can still find it on my work desktop come Monday.

Answer (score 2):

First see if there is a power of two that lies within your interval.  If there is at least one, the largest one wins.

Otherwise, choose the largest power of two that is less than your minimum bound.

Does 1100000...0 lie in your bound?  If yes, you've won.  If it's still less than your minimum bound, try 1110000...0; otherwise, if it's greater than your maximum bound, try 1010000...0.

And so forth, until you win.

Comment: ok, thanks. So both Rex' and your approach would take worst case O(log n) where n is the maximum number of bits (32). I was hoping for some O(1) magic, but this is actually fine.

Comment: Wouldn't it be O(n) in the bits?  I can see O(log n) if you take n to be, say, your interval maximum?  Or am I confusing things?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Since my numbers have a fixed word length (constant number of bits that doesn't change), this actually means it's O(1) regarding the size of the interval.

Answer (score 0):

as a conclusion, here is my variant of Rex' answer which gives both the center value and also an 'extent' which is the minimum power of two distance from the center which covers both `a` in the one direction and `b` in the other.

```
@tailrec def binSplit(a: Int, b: Int, mask: Int = 0xFFFFFFFF): (Int, Int) = {
  val mask2 = mask << 1
  if (a > (b & mask2)) (b & mask, -mask)
  else binSplit(a, b, mask2)
}

def test(): Unit = {
  val Seq(r1, r2) = Seq.fill(2)(util.Random.nextInt(0x3FFFFFFF) + 1)
  val (a, b) = if (r1 <= r2) (r1, r2) else (r2, r1)
  val (center, extent) = binSplit(a, b)
  assert((center >= a) && (center <= b) && (center - extent) <= a &&
         (center - extent) >= 0 && (center + extent) > b, (a, b, center, extent))
}

for (i <- 0 to 100000) { test() }
```